# How to Integrate Chrome's websql db with Angular 8?

Tags: google-chrome, angular8, web-sql

I am new to Angular. I am using version 8. In the process of learning Angular 8, I am trying to develop a CRUD Application and I am success to integrate with Angular's "InMemoryDbService". Here is the code.

This is `data.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {InMemoryDbService} from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService implements InMemoryDbService {

  constructor() { }

  createDb() {
    let persons = [
      {  id:  1,  firstName:  'A', lastName: 'B', emailId: 'AB@mail.com' },
      {  id:  1,  firstName:  'C', lastName: 'D', emailId: 'CD@gmail.com' },
      {  id:  1,  firstName:  'E', lastName: 'F', emailId: 'EF@gmail.com' },
      {  id:  1,  firstName:  'G', lastName: 'H', emailId: 'GH@mail.com' },
    ];
    return {persons};
  }
}
```

Here is my `person.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {Person} from './person';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8082/api/persons';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPerson(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }

  createPerson(person: Person) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}`, person);
  }

  updatePerson(id: number, value: any): Observable<object> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, value);
  }

  deletePerson(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }

  getPersonsList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  }
}
```

Now, I would like to do the same stuff by using google chrome's WebSQL database. I am not getting the right way to integrate that one. I saw lot of examples just using HTML5 along with Websql.(I will be able to do this by connecting to any REST API. But, I would like to do this completely from UI side). 
But, I haven't seen such examples which are explaining the integration of Angular 8 with Websql.

**How effectively I can make my Angular 8 service class to use WebSql?**

Any one please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you want to use WebSQL? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/Web-SQL it has been deprecated for quite some time

Comment: Yes. It's Chrome's websql. But, this is not for any official purpose. Just to improve some knowledge an angular8.

Comment: @PamuletiPullagura did you find sol to connect with websql and angular ?